# "Amplify hosting add" gives you the option of Hosting with Amplify Console. How to select the option using script/command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

How to select this using command automatically
[image]

Comment: was trying to automate the process involved in publishing the website, where i have to select this hosting type using script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple is the solution, yes,

"yes" is the solution,

`yes "" | amplify add hosting`